# Extracting text following periods as a separator of a specific line item

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract text that is delimited by periods. I'm a tad stumped after trying for too long and hoping someone can help!

In a nutshell, the following string (single string) is an example of a result of a query from column (e.g. Content).

Example string:

```
Some random text ........................... True
But really something ....................... Okay
Okay, just another test .................... 2010-04 is a good day
```

I'm trying to add some statements in the SELECT portion of the query to pull data out of Content in this example. All of the rows in the db have the same content, just with different "values" (True, Okay, 2010...).

Example result:

```
Col-Random     | Col2-Something  | Col3-Okay
---------------+-----------------+-------------------------
True           | Okay            | 2010-04 is a good day
```

I've tried variants of the following:

```
SELECT
regexp_extract(SUMMARY, r'/.*Some random text.*/g') as Col-Random
....
FROM `table`
```

Comment: I don't understand what results you want in each case.

Comment: In js, I can just do <string>.match(/.*Some random text.*/g)[0] for example, and that results to "True". I'm looking to do this all in SQL with BigQuery though, so all in the query using REGEXP_EXTRACT in the SELECT statement. I can't just for the life of me figure out regex that makes it work.

Comment: Add what you tried to the question. Comments are not meant for that. Note in JS, `.match(/.*Some random text.*/g)[0]` won't return `True`

Comment: @Ben - did you see the answer? you can apply it to whatever further needs you have! right?

Answer (score 1):

> ... trying to extract text that is delimited by periods

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Some random text ........................... True' line         UNION ALL
  SELECT 'But really something ....................... Okay'              UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Okay, just another test .................... 2010-04 is a good day' 
)
SELECT 
  SPLIT(line, REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r'(\.{3}[\.]+)'))[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] key,
  SPLIT(line, REGEXP_EXTRACT(line, r'(\.{3}[\.]+)'))[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] value       
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row key                         value    
1   Some random text            True     
2   But really something        Okay     
3   Okay, just another test     2010-04 is a good day
```

Note: above assumes minimum number of 4 periods to qualify as separator

so, if you have your line as `Some ... random text ........................... True` - it still will be properly processed to

```
key                     value    
Some ... random text    True
```